# "You can’t open the application because it is not supported on this type of Mac." xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode5.1

When I try to build my xcode project using the following command:

`xcodebuild -workspace "Converse.xcworkspace"  -sch
eme "Converse" -configuration “Debug” -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -arch i386  ONLY_
ACTIVE_ARCH=NO`

It builds fine, but when I try to double click on the app it generates, it says: `You can’t open the application because it is not supported on this type of Mac.` Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Because it is on iOS app, witch you can not just run by double clicking it in finder. You need to deploy it on the iOS simulator.

Comment: @rckoenes Ive always run my projects through xcode and not the command line. I am unfamiliar on how to do that. Could you post an answer on how to deploy it on the simulator please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS apps need the simulator to run. You can just, as you said run them from Xcode. If you do not have the project then you need to deploy them like :

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication /Path/ToIso.app/AppName`

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode, not xcodebuild, to run your app on the simulator.